# pyhon3 掛算リストで末尾に半角スペースを入れないで作成する仕方を教えてください。

Tags: python, python3

python3の入門をしている者ですが、
以下の条件を満たすコードをよりシンプルに書くには
どのような方法があるのでしょうか。

条件：
・入力値に対して、1から10をかける
・各整数の間に、半角スペース
・最終値の後ろに半角スペース、または改行が入るのはNG

私のコード：

```
num = int(input())
for i in range(1, 11):
    if i == 10:
        print(i * num)
    else:
        print(str(i * num) + " ", end="")
```

入力： 2

出力： 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

Comment: `str.join()` を使うと上手く行きそうですね。[Python String join() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)

Comment: ヒントをいただき、有難うございます！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

こんな感じでできます。

```
num = int(input())
print(" ".join(str(i * num) for i in range(1,11)), end="")
```

Comment: str.join()を利用したコードは、こうなるんですね！　すごくシンプルで、勉強になりました。　有難うございます！

Answer (score 1):

リストの内包表記を使用するバージョンです。

```
num = int(input())
print(" ".join([str((x+1)*num) for x in range(10)]),end="")
```

map関数を使用するバージョンです。

```
num = int(input())
print(" ".join(list(map(lambda x:str((x+1)*num),range(10)))),end="")
```

Comment: `for x in range(10)` のところで `x` が0から始まるので、このコードだと期待する出力とは異なる結果になります。

Comment: 確かに、ミスしました。すみません。指摘ありがとう。前回答と違うようにするために、x+1としました。

Comment: 他にも、 `最終値の後ろに半角スペース、または改行が入るのはNG` というのが満たされていないのと、リストの内包表記は不要（`[]`なしでそのままjoinに渡せる）であり、実質的に[dosec氏の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48817/pyhon3-%E6%8E%9B%E7%AE%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E6%9C%AB%E5%B0%BE%E3%81%AB%E5%8D%8A%E8%A7%92%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E4%BB%95%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84/48820#48820) と同じであることが気になります。

Comment: 見た目は同じですが、Python言語上での定義は異なります。dosec氏の回答の回答は、「ジェネレータ」となります。